# how to Edit a Sharepoint Calendar event Item on event Click in SPCalendarView control

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-api

I have created a custom Calendar, using the  `<SharePoint:SPCalendarView id=spcalView runat="server"> </SharePoint:SPCalendarView>`. 
Then I had inserted some events to the Calendar List, and its possible for me to display the events in the view spcalView created above. For this I passed `SPListItemCollection`(ie retrieved the collection from Calendar List) to a function `MakeSchedule()`.

```
private SPCalendarItemCollection MakeSchedule(SPListItemCollection calListItems)
        {

            SPCalendarItemCollection items = new SPCalendarItemCollection();
            for (int i = 0; i < calListItems.Count; i++)
            {
                SPListItem item = calListItems[i];
                DateTime StartTime = Convert.ToDateTime(item["EventDate"]);
                DateTime EndTime = Convert.ToDateTime(item["EndDate"]);
                string appointmentId = "";
                if (item["AppointmentID"] != null)
                    appointmentId = item["AppointmentID"].ToString();
                string clientID = "";
                if (item["clientID"] != null)
                    clientID = item["clientID"].ToString();

                string Description = "";
                if (item["Description"] != null)
                    Description = item["Description"].ToString();

                string Location = "";
                if (item["Location"] != null)
                    Location = item["Location"].ToString();

                string Title = "";
                if (item["Title"] != null)
                    Title = item["Title"].ToString();

                bool Recurrance = false;
                if (item["fRecurrence"] != null)
                    Recurrance = (bool)item["fRecurrence"];

                bool AllDayEvent = false;
                if (item["fAllDayEvent"] != null)
                    AllDayEvent = (bool)item["fAllDayEvent"];

                SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
                string relativeURL = web.ServerRelativeUrl;
                string absoluteURL = web.Url;

                items.Add(
                    new SPCalendarItem()
                    {
                        ItemID = item["ID"].ToString(),
                        StartDate = StartTime,
                        EndDate = EndTime,
                        hasEndDate = true,
                        Title = Title,
                        Location = Location,
                        Description = Description,
                        IsAllDayEvent = AllDayEvent,
                        IsRecurrence = Recurrance,
                        CalendarType = (int)SPCalendarType.Gregorian,
                        BackgroundColorClassName="ApptCnfirmed",

                        DisplayFormUrl = relativeURL + "/_layouts/TestProj.Webparts/AppointmentsEdit.aspx"
                    }
                    );
            }
            return items;
        }
```

Here in this for each event item added to the SPCalendarItemCollection, i had set the DisplayFormUrl to an application page. So when i click an event in Spcalendar view,it gets redirected to application page along with the ID of the item clicked as query string.

In the Application page, retrieved the ID, and based on the ID, I retrieved the currentLstItem. but from that i am not able to get the custom fields added by me in the CalendarList.

```
public partial class AppointmentsEdit : LayoutsPageBase
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string ID = Page.Request.QueryString["ID"].ToString();//this Id is the unique id of the Appointment List 
        string Source=Page.Request.QueryString["Source"].ToString();
        if (ID != "" && ID != null)
        {

            SPList lstApp = SPContext.Current.Web.Lists["Appointment"];
            SPListItem currentLstItem =            lstApp.GetItemById(Convert.ToInt32(ID.ToString()));


        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Is this the proper way to edit the calendar event?, because i have custom fields added to the Calendar List in sharepoint. I tried using designer but i am not able to get the code behind for the EditForm.aspx.

Thanks in advance!!